# What's the reason for different output here?

Tags: java

```
int a = 2;
int b = a + a;

Class cache = Integer.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0]; 
Field myCache = cache.getDeclaredField("cache"); 
myCache.setAccessible(true);

Integer[] newCache = (Integer[]) myCache.get(cache); 
newCache[132] =  newCache[133];

System.out.printf("%d",b); // 5
System.out.println(b); // 4
```

Here I change the value of `cache[132]` to `cache[133]` that means now `cache[132] == 5`
in `printf()` method it prints 5 fine but in `println()` why it prints 4 it should be 5 what's the reason behind on it?

Comment: You're fiddling around with the undocumented internals of a library class - why would you expect reasonable behaviour here?

Comment: You're using reflection here for what appears to be no real good reason.  It's unclear why you'd want to do this or what you're trying to accomplish.  Further, when you use reflection, a lot of the guarantees of object state and immutability become swiftly null and void, so tread with caution.

Comment: if you don't know the reason that's good but you can't say it "fiddling" @Oliver Charlesworth

Comment: @NewazSharifAmit:  No, it very much looks like "fiddling", even to me.  Be clear:  what is it you're actually trying to do?   Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Of course it's fiddling - there is no good reason for doing this.

Comment: What's wrong with being curios?

Comment: If you don't like the question, just avoid to comment or answer. Let the moderators do their job. Easy peasy.

Comment: @IvanValeriani This site is mostly community moderated. There's a limited amount of moderators, which is why they grant users moderation privileges based on their reputation. 4 people have already voted to close the question.

Comment: I think that if this question was asked by a higher rep user, it would have no close votes or downvotes and many more upvotes. People can vote how they like, but I can't see how it's unclear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 6):

`println` has an overload which accepts an `int`. Therefore in the line

```
System.out.println(b);
```

the `int` is never converted to an `Object` using `Integer.valueOf`.

`printf` has signature

```
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object ... args)
```

so `4` is autoboxed to the `Integer` object `5` (using the modified cache), and so `5` is printed.

Comment: This holds.  This is also why I couldn't see it in the debugger; the autobox had already taken effect when the `printf` was called.

Answer (score 1):

After javap -verbose package.YourClassName

```
    51: getstatic     #67                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    54: ldc           #73                 // String %d
    56: iconst_1
    57: anewarray     #3                  // class java/lang/Object
    60: dup
    61: iconst_0
    62: iload_2
    63: invokestatic  #75                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    66: aastore
    67: invokevirtual #79                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.printf:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    70: pop
    71: getstatic     #67                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    74: iload_2
    75: invokevirtual #85                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
    78: return
```

You see that at instruction 63 Integer.valueOf gets called, thus using the Integer cache. At point 75 println signature doesn't take an object but rather a straight primitive int, so no Integer cache involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you try below code

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(b));
```

You will notice 5 being printed for this. Now for the `printf` method you have below code.

```
System.out.printf("%d",b);
```

If you see `printf` accepts String as first parameter and Object as second parameter. You have b as primitive type (int). Auto boxing takes place and for it `Integer.java class method :  valueOf(int i)` is used.

Also if you declare Integer then you will see 4 being printed in both the cases as no auto boxing happens. usually -128 to 127 are cached and you have modified the internal cache. `valueOf` uses the cache and that is the reason you see different oputputs